# Controlling current through low value inductor

Tags: mosfet, pwm, inductor

I have an inductor on the order of 1uH whose current I want to regulate using a PWM signal using a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzw04Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where I have a microcontroller generating the 1MHz square wave, which would normally be a PWM signal.

According to my understanding, the PWM duty cycle should be maybe 1/10th or less of the L / R time constant (in this case, the L / R time constant is 10 microseconds).  Even though my circuit satisfies this requirement, the current going through the inductor in this simulation is very jagged, like this:

[image]
[image]

If I increase the PWM frequency to 10MHz, the signal is still jagged (which is what I would expect), but the amplitude of the current over time is much smaller, which is what I want.

[image]

**question**
Aside from having a faster PWM signal (not really an option... my MCU is only so fast) or having a lower ESR inductor (also kinda tough), what are my options for achieving this?

Do programmable current source IC's exist that would do the job for me?  Could I use a DAC + Op-amp and rely on the ESR of the inductor?

### Edit:

Using a 47uF capacitor with Dmitry Grigoryev's solution gives me a current output that is way closer to what I want.  The current won't need to be modulated very quickly, so using a higher value capacitor works well for me, and it lets me lower my pwm frequency to 180kHz, which is what my MCU can produce.

This is a current graph generated with 180kHz and 47uF capacitor
[image]

Still wondering if some sort of op-amp + BJT solution would be completely daft or not.

---

Comment: Take a step back ! You say *the current going through the inductor in this simulation is very jagged* then I say **that is to be expected**. Now think again what is happening in your circuit and relate that to what you want to happen.

Comment: 1 uH inductor will charge (magnetically !) very quickly since it is such a small value. A 1 MHz MCU-generated PWM signal is not very well suited for that. Try again with 100 uH.

Comment: I totally get that it will charge magnetically very quickly, but I was under the impression that, as long as my PWM frequency is about a factor of 10 lower than my L / R time constant, the pwm artifacts in the inductor current will be much lower.

Comment: At any rate, I can't try again with 100uH :).  The inductor I need to regulate is 1uH.

Comment: You might want to simulate the power dissipation in the MOSFET using your Edit circuit.

Comment: Would it make sense if the n MOSFET were on the low side of the circuit?

Comment: @Bradman175 I think that's a P mosfet?

Comment: @johnny_boy oh my bad.

Answer (score 5):

Add a capacitor to your circuit in parallel to the inductor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVHApW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pick the capacitance value so that the resonant frequency of your LC circuit is much lower than the PWM frequency yet much higher than the frequency of the current variations you want to produce. That way the resonance effects won't interfere significantly with the signal you're trying to generate.

Comment: If this is to be a real circuit, and not just a simulation, then you really need to consider both the ESR and the self-resonance of the capacitor. The ripple current supplied by this capacitor is of the order of amps. I'm pretty sure this is why such capacitors are almost never used in PWM motor control (motors are big inductive loads).

Comment: @DaveP Yes, those parameters need to be considered. Regarding PWM motor control, I think caps are not used there mainly because they are not needed, motors don't care about ripple.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach is to just add a suitable inductor (eg. 10uH or 20uH) in series with the one you are trying to control.

The two devices together will behave electrically as a 11 or 21uH inductor and the current through your 1uH will be much smoother.

Answer (score 2):

I think the current waveforms match what you'd expect from your circuit. With the standard inductor equation:

\$\frac{di}{dt} = \frac{V}{L} = \frac{3.3}{1 \times 10{-6}}=3.3\times10^6 As^{-1}\$

Once your circuit reaches steady state, the change in current over a single 0.5us period is approximately 1.3A, which is of the same order of magnitude as the expected change:

\$ 0.5 \times 10^{-6} \times 3.3\times10^6 = 1.65A \$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... makes sense.  I feel kinda dumb now!  I'm still looking for a standard technique for regulating this current though.  At least now I understand a little better why PWM is probably not the right tool even if the L / R time constant seems to work out on the surface.

Comment: Feeling dumb is pretty much how I've been through the last decade of being in the electrical engineering world. Feeling dumb with occasional bright spots of understanding.

Comment: That makes 2 of us :).  Being a computer engineer on EE projects is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon, you didn't notice that the inductor get saturated, i.e. it is not able to discharge its stored energy to 0 thus finally its dc current component is so high. The pwm is absolutely the right thing if only the circuit has a feedback loop and can vary duty cycle according to error. (i.e. difference: seen - expected current). But if the pwm duty is constant all the time then .. nothing to say than: dumb circuit -> dumb results.